# No File Chosen does not show on mobile sized screen

Tags: input, bootstrap-4, upload

I am using Bootstrap 4 and have created a simple file input for file upload.

```
    <input type="file" id="txtFiles" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" class="form-control">
```

It looks fine on mid-sized and large screens, but I notice for smaller, mobile screens the text "No file chosen." goes away.  On a larger screen, when the user selects a file, the text shows the file they've chosen.  Here is what it looks like when I use Google Chrome tools to simulate the mobile view:

[image]

On the mobile screen, it does not.  What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: can you share the code which replicates this issue for us to see.. it is not visible with the following code: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="txtFiles" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01" class="form-control">
</body>
</html>
`

Comment: I basically have what you have except no <html lang="en"> just <html>